# Invert the matrix values

Tags: python

I have a

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to print "a" the a like matrix form however like columnwise :

```
 1 4 7 
 2 5 8
 3 6 9
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print a [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) matrix like this:

```
def print_row_maj(m):
    for row in m:
       print ' '.join(str(x) for x in row)
```

Combine this with [sashkello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22397041/119527) to print your transposed (not inverted!) matrix.

```
def transpose(m):
    return zip(*m)

a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]    

print_row_maj( transpose(a) )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can transpose it using `zip`:

```
print zip(*a)
>>> [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

It should work for any shape, not only square matrix. The only situation it gives dodgy result is when `a` has one row.

You can print it in your desired form using `join`:

```
for el in a:
    print " ".join(str(s) for s in el)
```

Or, as suggested by @ssm, a one-liner:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(*a))
```

And finally, using numpy:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,x)) for x in np.transpose(a))
```

Comment: Also, it needs to be converted to string like so: `'\n'.join( [' '.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(*a)] )`. Good use of the zip(*)!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print, you can do the following, although I do assume that the matrix is rectangular.

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in xrange(len(a[0])):
   print " ".join(str(a[j][i]) for j in xrange(len(a)))
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, Fair enough. I am interpreting the question literally though. If the user accepts the other answer, I will delete this one.

Comment: @user2864740, I removed the hardcoded bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrnew = new Array();
arrnew = [[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 7], [5, 6, 9]];

for (var i = 0; i < arrnew.length; i++) {
console.log(arrnew[i][0] + " " + arrnew[i][1] + " " + arrnew[i][2]);
```

}